# Getting data from ifstream that failed conversion

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm using an `ifstream` object to read `double`'s from a text-file.

```
ifstreamObject >> floatVariable;
```

In the case that the read is not able to be converted into a `double`, I wondering how I can get the non-convertable data and make it into a `string` instead? Is it possible doing it this way without first storing it as a `string` and then try to convert it?

I want to do it this way so that the object throws an exception. The `catch`-block is intended to handle the values that are not convertable to `double` and store them in a separate txt-file for later analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tellg to find current location and if conversion failed use seekg to go backwards and convert it to string.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the important thing is to remember to clear the error that you get when the read fails:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");

    float f;
    if(ifs >> f)
    {
        // deal with float f
        std::cout << "f: " << f << '\n';
    }
    else // failed to read a float
    {
        ifs.clear(); // clear file error

        std::string s;
        if(ifs >> s)
        {
            // now deal with string s
            std::cout << "s: " << s << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend against using `try{} catch{}` exceptions for this because non-convertable input is one of your ***expected*** results. That is not truly ***exceptional***.